# How to get most recent favorites of user, in order of favorited

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm using twitter4j to create a twitter bot that detects certain users' most recent likes. However, whenever I use

```
List<Status> statuses = twitter.getFavorites();
for(int i = 0; i < statuses; i++){
    System.out.println(statuses.get(i));
}
```

The output is the tweets in the order they were composed by the original poster. Is there any way to sort/get the tweets in the order they were favorited by the user instead?

Comment: It seems the `twitter4j.Status` object has a [getCreatedAt() method](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html#getCreatedAt--), so you could sort on that. If you use Java 8+ you can use `statuses.sort(Comparator.comparing(Status::getCreatedAt));` for example. If you use java 7 or lower, take a look at `Collections.sort` with custom `Comparator` instead. NOTE: I don't know anything about twitter4j, so I'm not sure if it creates a new Status every time a user changes their favorite. If it re-uses `Status`-objects, or uses the `getCreatedAt` for something else, I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Unfortunately getCreatedAt() returns the date the tweet was composed, and I need the date the tweet was favorited by a user. Twitter doesn't create a new status when a user favorites something.

Comment: Ah ok, I was afraid something like that might be the case. In that case I'm not really able to help you. The `getFavorites()` method only seems to return the 20 most recent favorite statuses, but it doesn't specify the order.